# Change the output of the [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables('Machine') command in powershell OR get the list of the names of the environment var

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, output

I'm trying to list the system environment variables in Powershell, and to change the output to something like :

```
NAME=VALUE
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
TMP=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP
```

So something with name=value and a return to the line after all variable

The problem is that I can't make this output, the only thing I can found is :

```
Name  : NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS
Value : 8

Name  : windir
Value : C:\WINDOWS
```

using the command :

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables('Machine') | Format-List
```

This first one is almost what I want but it's still not perfect.

Or I can also have :

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS           8
TMP                            C:\WINDOWS\TEMP
windir                         C:\WINDOWS
```

using the command :

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables('Machine') | Format-Table
```

Which is badder than the first one because the line are cut (the path is not fully displayed because its to large to be printed on the screen)

I tried to put the output in a variable and only get the name of the variables but it still doesn't work :

```
PS> $array=[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables('Machine')
PS> $array[0].Name
```

and also tried "Get-Member" to get all the variable names but it don't show what I need :

```
PS> $array[0] | Get-Member

   TypeName : System.Collections.Hashtable

Name              MemberType            Definition
----              ----------            ----------
Add               Method                void Add(System.Object key, System.Object value), void IDiction...
Clear             Method                void Clear(), void IDictionary.Clear()
Clone             Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()
Contains          Method                bool Contains(System.Object key), bool IDictionary.Contains(Sys...
ContainsKey       Method                bool ContainsKey(System.Object key)
ContainsValue     Method                bool ContainsValue(System.Object value)
CopyTo            Method                void CopyTo(array array, int arrayIndex), void ICollection.Copy...
Equals            Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetEnumerator     Method                System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator(), Syste...
GetHashCode       Method                int GetHashCode()
GetObjectData     Method                void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationIn...
GetType           Method                type GetType()
OnDeserialization Method                void OnDeserialization(System.Object sender), void IDeserializa...
Remove            Method                void Remove(System.Object key), void IDictionary.Remove(System....
ToString          Method                string ToString()
Item              ParameterizedProperty System.Object Item(System.Object key) {get;set;}
Count             Property              int Count {get;}
IsFixedSize       Property              bool IsFixedSize {get;}
IsReadOnly        Property              bool IsReadOnly {get;}
IsSynchronized    Property              bool IsSynchronized {get;}
Keys              Property              System.Collections.ICollection Keys {get;}
SyncRoot          Property              System.Object SyncRoot {get;}
Values            Property              System.Collections.ICollection Values {get;}
```

I also found that if you type :

```
$array[0].TMP
```

It shows you the value of the variable which is in my case :

```
C:\WINDOWS\TEMP
```

In that case I want to get the list of the variable name to make a loop which call $array[0].Name, where name is the name of the variable (and i did not code it yet because I can't get this list)

So my questions are :

**How can I get the list of the environment variable names (TEMP, USERNAME, etc) ?**

**How can I change my output to make it looks like name=value ?**

Comment: Don't add a parameter : [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables() | Format-Table

Comment: @jdweng it only shows the user environment variables, and the format-table cut the line for to long values (like the value of the PATH) so you don't help me -_-

Comment: I'm seeing 50 variables.  How many do you see?  From cmd.exe >Set will show all the variables.  Also from start button type "Edit Environment Variables" which shows 5 user and 26 system variables.

Comment: I'm seeing 39 of them, I know that the "set" command shows environment variables but if the user have modified one of them, the system one is not showed. And my goal was to get them using powershell (which I already know how to use it to show these variables) and change the output of the command
PS : thx for your help but someone already answered my question 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`GetEnvironmentVariables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariables?view=net-7.0#system-environment-getenvironmentvariables) outputs [`IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary?view=net-7.0) you can enumerate each Key / Value pair using the [`GetEnumerator` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary.getenumerator?view=net-7.0#system-collections-idictionary-getenumerator):

```
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables('Machine').GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    '{0}={1}' -f $_.Key, $_.Value
}
```

If you would like to list only a specific set of Environment Variables you could change the logic and use [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getenvironmentvariable) instead to target specific ones:

```
$variablesOfInterest = 'TEMP', 'USERNAME'
$variablesOfInterest | ForEach-Object {
    '{0}={1}' -f $_, [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($_)
}
```

Regarding:

> How can I get the list of the environment variable names (TEMP, USERNAME, etc) ?

Same as with any other type implementing `IDictionary`, you can call it's [`.Keys` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary.keys?view=net-7.0#system-collections-idictionary-keys):

```
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables('Machine').Keys
```

Comment: Did the "System." is mandatory when you write [System.Environment] ? I was only using [Environment] before . (And thx a lot, your answer entirely solved my problem)

Comment: @ThomasMONTIGNY `System` is not really needed at all :P it's just that my VS Code autocompletes with the Class Fully Qualified Name. An happy to help :)